# Is any way to rate the youtube video using any google or youtube API?

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am struggling with a problem to rate an youtube video through an android app. I am using `google-client-api,youtube api, google play services`. So i am able to perform `OAuth2.0` authenication using AccountManager. and also able to upload video on youtube. but i didnt find ay link for rating a youtube video. is there any link or tutorial or sample for the doing the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done by using YouTubeAPI v2.0. See the specification 
on [this link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_ratings)

```
POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/ratings
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
       xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
  <gd:rating value="4" min="1" max="5"/>
</entry>
```

Comment: Link is working https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_ratings