# Youtube API - Like a Video PHP

Tags: php, api, youtube

```
$ratevideo = $youtube->videos->rate($vid,'like');
```

This above code im using for Rate a Youtube Video for a athenticated User, but it wont work.

```
$ratevideo = $youtube->videos->rate($vid,'dislike');
```

The Dislike Function works perfectly. 
Everytime i dislike a video every User is counting. 
When im trying to like a Video it wont work.

Anybody can help ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [YouTube API v3 likes a video, but the counter doesn't increase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137281/youtube-api-v3-likes-a-video-but-the-counter-doesnt-increase)

Comment: is it a library you are using?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503305/is-any-way-to-rate-the-youtube-video-using-any-google-or-youtube-api/26504844#26504844

Answer (score 0):

Youtube doesn't display the info live. They update periodicly.

see this video for more info: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIkhgagvrjI

Comment: this likes are nothing to do with freeze views. How you can explain that dislikes are displayed live ? and likes not ?

Comment: But since youtube update their like count periodicly you won't notice the difference at first. Just like when it freezes

Comment: that explains the first answer to my question :-)